# I am trying to find the correlation between theravada jhana, rupa/arupa and the 9 levels of calm abiding in tibetan buddhism

Tags: theravada, jhana, samatha, tibetan

Title really.
I am reading the tibetan lamrim version of the 9 mental abiding and trying to correlate it to the theravada 8 jhanas, I can't seem to find which jhana/abiding is which in regards to the other tradition.

The practice for both is still samatha.

If anyone has an informed opinion or understanding of the practices I could really do with some help understanding how the 2 different explanations coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Gelugpa's Lamrim tradition for sure, and I suspect in most other Lamrim traditions as well, the four rupa jhanas and the subsequent arupa jhanas are practiced *after* the 9 abidings, once the calm abiding has been achieved.

Please refer to [Meditative States in Tibetan Buddhism](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/086171119X), page 85.

Comment: I was actually reading that book as well as other books to find the answer and eventually got to the understanding that the 9 calm abiding are what as knows as access concentration, a prerequisite to jhana meditations.